# Updating Canvas? invalidate()?

Tags: android, canvas, invalidation

Hi im trying to get my app to update a canvas from a custom view i made
This view creates a square with lines and a circle in the center.
I want to press a button and draw random x and y coordinates to the canvas.

Heres My MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
//  EditText numDart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numDarts);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public int convertToDpi(int px){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int unit = metrics.widthPixels/20;
    return px * unit;
}
public void drawCanvas(View v){
    View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.canView);
    Paint black = new Paint();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    view.invalidate(); //dont know where to go from here
}
```

Heres My Custom View:

```
public CanView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect myrect = new Rect();
    myrect.set(-10, 10, 10, -10);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    Paint white = new Paint();
    white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    white.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Paint black = new Paint();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


    canvas.drawRect(myrect, blue);
    canvas.drawCircle(convertToDpi(10), convertToDpi(10),convertToDpi(3), white);
    canvas.drawLine(convertToDpi(10), 0, convertToDpi(10), convertToDpi(20), black);
    canvas.drawLine(0, convertToDpi(10), convertToDpi(20), convertToDpi(10), black);
    canvas.scale(5, 5, 0, 0);
}
@Override
public void postInvalidate() {  //Logic for redrawig goes here??? 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.postInvalidate();
}

public int convertToDpi(int px){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int unit = metrics.widthPixels/20;
    return px * unit;
}
```

I dont get how to reference the canvas from my Custom View and change or redraw it. Im assuming you use invalidate(); but im puzzled on how this method works can any1 help me out?

Answer (score 3):

When `invalidate` is called `onDraw` is called again, you should also use `this.getHolder().addCallback(this);` and let your class implement `Callback` and add the unimplemented methods

Comment: hmm do u mean implementing Callback to the main activity? and what class do i use getHolder().addCallBack? sorry if these are stupid questions im really new to android

Comment: It should be in the class of the view, doing it the way you are it appears you are extending `SurfaceHolder` it should be that class that you implement it on,.

Comment: @FabianCook OP is probably not using SurfaceHolder, instead simply extending the View and using its OnDraw call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to draw the view only. First of set your contentview as the View where you are drawing on the canvas. Your are setting your contnet view only as the main layout. If you want to see the View where you drawing on canvas. set that view to your contentView.

setContentView(canView);

Now if you want that button too, then create a relative layout and add the button view and this canView to that relative layout ans set this as your contentView.